# Downloading large base64encoded data using NsurlConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am trying to download a large file from server using **POST** request. The file is received as **base64Encoded** data. The file size is over 400Mb. The first approach that i used was to append the data that was received in **didReceiveData** and then in **connectionDidFinishLoading** i use to **decode** the data and write the data to file in documents directory. This approach works for files with small sizes. But it crashes as the file size is very big (400MB). I then used the approach of NSFileHandle to write the file in chunks as the data is received. I used the chunks of 3MB to write the data. For files smaller than 3MB the received data is directly decoded from base64 and the file is created successfully. But when the file size is greater then 3MB and i try to decode the chunk data from base64 using "**initWithBase64EncodedData: Options**" the data that i get is nil. Would like to know the what i am doing wrong in the code.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSString* folderPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Documents/UserDocs"];
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]  fileExistsAtPath:folderPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
   }

NSString *strFilePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];    NSString *newFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", strFilePath, strFileExtension];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]  fileExistsAtPath:newFilePath]) {
          [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:newFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        }

self.fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:newFilePath] retain];
        [self.fileHandle seekToFileOffset:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    NSUInteger chunkSize = 300000;
    if( receivedData.length > chunkSize  && self.fileHandle!=nil) {

        NSData *chunk = [receivedData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, chunkSize)];
        NSData *writableData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedData:chunk options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
       [receivedData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, chunkSize) withBytes:NULL length:0];

       [self.fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
       [self.fileHandle writeData:writableData];
       [writableData release];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    if (receivedData)
    {
        NSData *writableData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedData:receivedData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
        [receivedData release];

        [self.fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [self.fileHandle writeData:writableData];
        [writableData release];

        NSLog(@"File Write Success!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Base64 isn't a 1-to-1 encoding scheme, is it, so you will have data from the previous *chunk* that is needed in the current *chunk*.  You should investigate the possibility of using some form of base-64 stream decoder where you can just feed it chunks of input data and tell it where to write the decoded data.

Comment: Try NSStream, stream of data file and decode/encode on the fly to make one binary, let me know if works with the code :)

Comment: Are you in control over the server?  If so, why not just send the data as-is without doing the base64 encoding?  For example, you could use a multipart MIME response if you need to send back additional data beyond the large blob.  Or better yet, provide the metadata first, and in that, provide a URL where you can request the large data file unencoded with a second request.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches:

1. Skip the base64 encoding (if you can).
2. Write the data to disk as you get it, then use memory mapping to map the file into RAM where you can work with it as though it were in memory, but without actually occupying memory.

Basically:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
...
NSURL *url = // path to file on disk
char *path = [url fileSystemRepresentation];
struct stat buf;

// Round up to an exact multiple of the page size
NSUInteger size = (buf.st_size + PAGE_MASK) & ~PAGE_MASK;
NSData *data = nil;

if (!stat(path, &buf)) {
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd != -1) {
        mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
        data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:buf.st_size];
    }
}

// Perform a base64 decode on the NSData object and hope that
// at least the result will fit in RAM.

// Clean up.
data = nil;
if (!stat(path, &buf)) {
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd != -1) {
        munmap(addr, size);
    }
}
```

Creating a base64 decoder that can write the data directly to a file on disk is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: I was not able to find a base64 decoder so I skipped the base64 encoding. Instead of base64 now the server returns the file stream and i use the same  code that i have mentioned in the question.